# how to insert and update multiple values at a time

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table

`customer_assignments` having `customer_id`, and `category_id` columns.

I want to insert multiple category _id's like 1,2,3  by customer_id=62 at a time ..the table look's like

```
customer_id  category_id 

    62          1
    62          2
    62          3
```

suppose if I update `category _id`s like 1,2 by `customer_id=62`, the table look's like

```
customer_id  category_id 

    62          1
    62          2
```

insert and update both will occur at a time....am new to mysql

I need query...

Comment: Do you mean to say that when updated with `1,2`, the existing record with id `3` be removed? For that you need a `delete` but not `update`.

Comment: delete everything for cust 62 and insert again on update

Answer (score 0):

use 2 queries
1.
DELETE * FROM customer_assignments 
2.
then now insert waht ever u want using INSERT query